# TreeView Edit Delete Insert using context menu

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Hai my problem is i want to create a application on treeView in Asp- web application and i want to delete update and insert nodes to treeview using context menu i worked on tha t but i get selected id on mouse left click but my context menu is opening on rigth click plaese help me in this aspect

Comment: Please put some more effort in your question. Show us some code. What have you done, what exactly is your problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Asp:Treeview does not implement basically this option, you must add javascript.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview_properties

I prefer Ajax .net control for this implementation

http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/treeview/features/node_contextMenus/WebForm1.aspx

For Jquery - Context menu

```
contextMenu('yourMenu', {
    bindings: {
        'delete': function(f) { ShowAction(f, "Delete"); }
    }
});

function ShowAction(f, a) {
    alert('Item is ' + f.id + '\nAction is' + a + "\nHtml is " + $(f).html());
}
```

Comment: am  using jquery to contextmenu but my problem is in order to delete a node iwant to know the selected node id but on right click how to get the selected noid id